# How can a process appear to have different name in ps output?

Tags: linux, process

recently I had to clean up a hacked server. The malicious process would appear as "who" or "ifconfig eth0" or something like that in "ps aux" output, even tough the executable was just a jumble of letters, which was shown in /proc/[pid]/status .

I'm curious as to how the process managed to mask itself like that.

Comment: What's type of the execuable?

Comment: It was binary, not a shell script if that's what you ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manipulating the name in the process list is a common practice. E.g. I have in my process listing the following:

```
root      9847  0.0  0.0  42216  1560 ?        Ss   Aug13   8:27 /usr/sbin/dovecot -c /etc/dovecot/d
root     20186  0.0  0.0  78880  2672 ?        S    Aug13   2:44  \_ dovecot-auth
dovecot  13371  0.0  0.0  39440  2208 ?        S    Oct09   0:00  \_ pop3-login
dovecot   9698  0.0  0.0  39452  2640 ?        S    Nov07   0:00  \_ imap-login
ericb     9026  0.0  0.0  48196  7496 ?        S    Nov11   0:00  \_ imap [ericb 192.168.170.186]
```

Dovecot uses this mechanism to easily show what each process is doing.

It's basically as simple as manipulating the `argv[0]` parameter in C. `argv` is an array of pointers to the parameters with which the process has been started. So a command `ls -l /some/directory` will have:

```
argv[0] -> "ls"
argv[1] -> "-l"
argv[2] -> "/some/directory"
argv[3] -> null
```

By allocating some memory, putting some text in that memory, and then putting the address of that memory in `argv[0]` the process name shown will have been modified to the new text.

Comment: It does not work quite like that. Pointing `argv[0]` to a different location doesn't change how the process appears to `ps`. The kernel doesn't care about the pointers in `argv`. Rather the kernel remembers which range of memory the actual arguments is in and makes that visible to `ps` and other tools. Those tools will then have to identify the boundaries between the arguments by looking for the NUL termination between each argument.

Answer (score 7):

Changing argv[] is not portable. On Linux you can't simply change argv[0] to point to a longer string either. You'd have to overwrite the existing arguments and take care not to overwrite the environment variables that follow in the address space.

[libbsd](https://libbsd.freedesktop.org/wiki/) provides an implementation of [setproctitle(3)](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libbsd-dev/setproctitle.3bsd.en.html) for Linux that makes this much easier.

Answer (score 6):

There are two Linux-standard ways to do this, one of which comes from glibc and might be portable to other non-Linux systems:

- glibc [`pthread_setname_np()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setname_np) is probably the better method
- Linux [`prctl()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/prctl) also works

It's possible that changing `argv[0]` used to work, but at least on my current Linux system it does nothing to the output in `ps`.

See this answer for more details and a code example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55584492/737303

Answer (score 3):

In language like `C`, a process can change its name by changing `argv[0]`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    argv[0][2] = 'A';
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile it:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ls
a.out
$ ./a.out
```

In other terminal:

```
$ ps -ef | grep '[a].out'
$ ps -ef | grep '[A].out'
cuonglm  17979 17569  0 14:51 pts/0    00:00:00 ./A.out
```

Higher level language also allows you to do this, example in `Perl`, you can modify [$0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%240) variable to change process name.

Answer (score -2):

It is common for a hacker/rootkit/exploit to immediately replace the various systems tools such as /bin/bash, /bin/ps, /bin/ls, etc., with hacked versions which modify the output to hide their hacked scripts/executables but otherwise behave the same.

For this reason, I recommend using a physical CD in any physical servers that you can reference a copy of known-good basic utilities. This way, if you suspect a compromise, you can reference a version of these tools which are read-only and are known to be safe.

Comment: This does not answer the question.